# how to open an in app browser like the mailcomposion popup

Tags: iphone

is it possible to open an in-app browser that loads a pdf and the takes you back to the nib just like the mailcomposition does with the in-app email? If so, can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a .xib and corresponding view controller (both named WebViewViewController here).  This should include a UIWebView (to display the PDF) and a UIButton (to close the modal view & return to your original view).

2) Present your WebViewViewController as a modal view.  This will "pop-over" your current view with the new view.

```
WebViewViewController *webViewVC = [[WebViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewViewController" bundle:nil];

//I am showing it over a Navigation Controller, you may be using something different.
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:webViewVC animated:YES];

[webViewVC release];
```

3) In your WebViewViewController, wire up an IBAction method to your "Close" button.  In that method use this to dismiss the "pop-over" view.

```
//
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

- Let me know if you need help with loading the PDF into the UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a UIWebView controlled by a custom UIViewController, which you present using the presentModalViewController:animated: method in the view controller that wants to pop up the PDF.